# Don't show DatePicker on input focus, only icon click

Tags: antd

The docs doesn't mention this, but does anyone know if it's possible to only show the DatePicker on icon click (or button), and not when the input field receives focus?

Users will primarily enter dates using the keyboard and doesn't want the DatePicker displayed, unless specifically asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/react-component/calendar) for the complete API which has some options that are not documented on the AntDesign site. But there is no option to achieve what you are looking for.

You need the combination of a text input with a button to popup the picker, which is a different paradigm from the one `<DatePicker>` uses. It could be "hacked" by combining a normal `<Input>`, `<DatePicker>` with custom CSS that only shows the button, and some Javascript event handlers.

Comment: making the same thing now. it's the only way to crack this task